# What's the easiest way to validate this date format, eg, 31-JUL-2010 (and only this fmt)

Tags: vb.net

I would like to easily validate dates in this format and only this format. Any otehr format should be considered invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx). You pass through the exact format string.

In your case the format string would be `d-MMM-yyyy` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)) and can be used as follows:

```
string dateString = "31-JUL-2010";
string format = "d-MMM-yyyy";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim DateToTest As String = "01-Apr-1964"
Dim ResultDate As Date

Date.TryParseExact(DateToTest, "dd-MMM-yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, ResultDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if regex is possible in VB.NET, but then it'll be relatively easy:

/[0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}/

This might be a bit language specific when it comes down to escaping characters and matching certain groups.

Comment: While regex is surely a valid approach your sample would allow `99-fOO-0000` which isn't a valid date.

Comment: This is true -- but I shouldn't have answered this question since I also kind of knew there were API functions who would be much better at this.

Comment: Truth is I'm a total looser with regex beyond your sample so I hoped you would take it a step further and give me something to go "Ah!".